# How to mask/clip the bottom part of an Image in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

Currently masking an image in SwiftUI seems really easy and can either be achieved using something like:

```
.clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius:20,
                                        style: .continuous))
```

or even `.mask()`. Is there a way of controlling which part of the image is masked by specifying `.center`, `.bottom`, .etc? So far I've been playing around with the offset but I was wondering if there might be a simpler way.

Answer (score 5):

`.clipShape()` needs a shape, so if you are going to be clipping the bottom often, you may create an ad hoc shape. Something like this:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Image("mypic")
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .clipShape(BottomClipper(bottom: 100))
    }
}

struct BottomClipper: Shape {
    let bottom: CGFloat

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        Rectangle().path(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: rect.size.height - bottom, width: rect.size.width, height: bottom))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

## Swift 1.0

You can combine padding with the shape. This might be the simpler way you were looking for?

```
Image("profile")
    // Add padding to sides of the shape to control what is masked
    .mask(Rectangle().padding(.bottom, 20))
    .border(Color.orange)
```

(Excerpt from the book "SwiftUI Views")
[image: SwiftUI Views Book Page]