# SwiftUI - How to show shadow only on top side?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to give shadow to my VStack (only at top) but when I do like below shadow is visible to all sides like button, Text. But I am trying to give border to only container.

```
.background(Color.white // any non-transparent background
               .shadow(color: Color.red, radius: 10, x: 0, y: 0)
             )
```

I want UI like below
[image]

Thank you for help

Comment: Can you create a minimal, reproducible example? It's hard to see the shadows in the image, and some simple example code which demonstrates the problem would allow us to help

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Try using the [`mask(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/mask(_:)) modifier, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58035985/14351818).

```
.background(
    Color.white // any non-transparent background
        .shadow(color: Color.red, radius: 10, x: 0, y: 0)
        .mask(Rectangle().padding(.top, -20)) /// here!
)
```

Result:

[image: Red shadow only on top]

Comment: .mask is Deprecated is there any alternative for now?

Comment: Use `.mask { /* ... */ }`

Answer (score 15):

You could put a `LinearGradient` at the top of a `VStack` to achieve the "top shadow" effect.

```
VStack(spacing: 0) {
   LinearGradient(colors: [.white, Color(.sRGB, white: 0.85, opacity: 1)], startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
       .frame(height: 6)
       .opacity(0.8)

    // ContinueButton()...
}
```

Result:

[image: topShadowExample]

Answer (score 3):

As you only want the shadow to come on the top it would be better to use the offset values of the `.shadow`. I would suggest moving it roughly double the radius.

like this:

```swift
.shadow(color: Color.red, 
        radius: 10, 
        x: -20, // Horizontal offset
        y: 0) // Vertical offset
```

Comment: This doesn't work as expected though, there will also be a shadow at the bottom of the view.

Answer (score 1):

```
.shadow(color: Color.black, 
        radius: 5, 
        x: 5, // (left shadow "-X" & right shadow "+X")
        y: -5) // (top shadow "-Y" & bottom shadow "+Y")
```